# Python - how to get access to SharePoint site without access to root

Tags: python, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, shareplum

I'm trying to read data from an HTML table that on a site with a URL like https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/sitepages/tables

And I only have access to the "mySite" site. I've tried using shareplum like their documentation:

```py
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365

authcookie = Office365('https://abc.sharepoint.com', username='username@abc.com', password='password').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/MySharePointSite/', authcookie=authcookie)
```

But I then get the following error: "requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: [https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/MySharePointSite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"](https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/MySharePointSite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx%22)

I'm guessing that this is precisely because I don't have access to the root site, but I've also tried doing:

```py
authcookie = Office365('https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/MySharePointSite/', username='username@abc.com', password='password').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/MySharePointSite/', authcookie=authcookie)
```

But that generated the same error.

Does anyone know a way to specify to shareplum that I want to use my credentials for that specific site, or a way without using shareplum entirely?

Comment: I am also having this problem. Would love to hear if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Issue [#105](https://github.com/jasonrollins/shareplum/issues/105) on the SharePlum GitHub repo suggests a workaround:
in shareplum/request_helper.py, comment out the following line in the `post` function (ln.17 for v0.5.1): `response.raise_for_status()`

This results in accepting the 403 return status, which you get for not having access to the root site. For me this solved the problem as the authentication actually was successful, and I could use the returned `authcookie` to work with the SharePoint sub-site.